# Android add onClick to dynamically created gallery item

Tags: android

I am trying to create a gallery that will show a picture fullscreen when you tap on the thumbnail.

I followed sort of a tutorial which nicely created the gallery, but I don't know how to give each image thumbnail an onClick event.

In my gallery page, inside the onCreate, I have this:

```
public class GalleryPage extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_page);
        ...
        this.imageGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gallery_container);
        this.bitmapList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        File f = new File(latest_directory);
        File file[] = f.listFiles();
        for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++) {
            this.bitmapList.add(loadImage(latest_directory + "/" + file[i].getName()));
        }
        this.imageGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, this.bitmapList));
    }
}
```

Then, the ImageAdapter looks like this:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bitmapList = bitmapList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.bitmapList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(this.context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(this.bitmapList.get(position));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

I was thinking I could just do:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener("onImageClick");
```

and have a method in my gallery page, but this throws an error.

How can I make it so when I click on any of the dynamically created gallery images (`imageView`), I can get the image location to pull the image and place it in a full size overlay.

Comment: Do you want to make click on adapter or in Activity?

Comment: @user3676184, Sorry, I've added that in now - it's a GridView that is the container

Comment: @KishanVaghela, In the Activity for the gallery page

Comment: You should pass an object implementing View.OnClickListener interface to setOnClickListener method, not a String.

Comment: listView.setItemClickListener not working?

Comment: use imageGrid.setOnItemClickListener and check

Comment: @thetonrifles, Yes, you're correct.  When I tried that anyways, I wasn't able to use a method used in the main activity because the method was not created in the adapter

Comment: @KishanVaghela & @user3676184, I haven't tried `setOnItemClickListener`, I will look into this now

Comment: @ntgCleaner Yes, this is clear, you could pass View.OnClickListener to the Adapter from outside, for example by adding parameter to Adapter constructor. This is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `OnItemClickListener` to the `GridView`.

```
imageGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {

        //Selected bitmap
        Bitmap bitMap = bitmapList.get(position);

        //Do something with it
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks pretty good, though `bitmapList` and `imageGrid` are in two separate classes.  the `imageGrid` is in the galleryPage activity, while the `bitmapList` is in the adapter.  Is there a way to still get `bitmapList` while in the gallerypage activity?

Comment: @ntgCleaner see my answer

Comment: But when you create the `Adapter` you have a `bitmapList`. Cant you get the data from the `bitmapList`?

Comment: Yes, the 'bitmapList' is created in adapter, but it is not accessible in the gallery page

Comment: @ntgCleaner I mean this line in GalleryPage, `this.imageGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, this.bitmapList));`. You can use `bitmapList` from this.

Comment: Yes, Sorry - I just noticed this - Not sure why it cannot be resolved. looking into it

Comment: doing some testing - I will let you know

Comment: I can't seem to get `bitmapList[position]` to work.  I'm unsure as to where to pull it from

Comment: Perfect, I am able to click on any gallery image now and I can use that bitmap.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `setOnItemClickListener`. 
If you want use your custom interface then follow this :

Create Interface

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Bitmap t, int position);
}
```

In your adapter set Listener:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
/// your code
private ItemClickListener listener;

public void setListener(ItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
// your code
}
```

In getView method

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // your code
        Bitmap bitmap =  this.bitmapList.get(position);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap );
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (listener != null)
                            listener.onItemClick(bitmap,position);
                    }
                });
        return imageView;
    }
```

That's it. Now implement this in your Activity.

Comment: I have this almost implemented - though on your last code view, the `bitmap, getAdapterPosition()` cannot be resolved

Comment: Pass your bitmap and position in getView. You have both in getView method.

Comment: Thank you, it all checks out, but now my images aren't showing in the gallery - checking into this now

Comment: I will when the application returns to working order including the answers provided here.  Thanks